# using mongodb and redis together in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, redis

I am curious how to setup both mongodb and redis for a single rails3 app? I googled but nothing found. any good idea? Thanks.

Comment: sorry, but what is the problem with this?

Comment: MongoDB and Redis are different data storage engines. In general, an application writes to a single data storage engine. What exactly are you trying to do? Write all data to both? Write some data to one and some data to the other?

Answer (score 1):

Both mongo and redis have excellent ruby clients that can be used within rails3. You could create a rails project excluding the creation of activerecord and simply use instances of models created with either the mongo or redis client. I have actually used ohm for something similar for redis with rails and highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

For setting up Mongo with Rails, take a look at [MongoMapper](http://mongomapper.com/). MongoDB got a [great guide on MongoMapper and Rails](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started) aswell. When creating a Rails project, just remember not to include ActiveRecord. You can do that with the `rails new my_app --skip-active-record` switch. This is all mentioned in the guide, you should give it a read.

For Redis, I'm not sure what your use case is. Most common ones for Rails are things like [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque). You should first take a look at the [Redis.io](http://redis.io/) website. Then take a look at the [redis-rb Ruby gem](https://github.com/ezmobius/redis-rb), it's really quite simple.